# Global struct in c

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to initialize global structs to be used as a linked list. I have tried several things already but I have basically this:

```
#includes....

struct reuqest_struct
{
struct timeval request_time;    
int type;           
int accountNums[10];        
int transAmounts[10];       
struct request_struct *next;    
struct request_struct *prev;    

};

// global structs I want
struct request_struct head;
struct request_struct tail;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

   head = {NULL, 5, NULL, NULL, tail, NULL};
   tail = {NULL, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, head};

}

void * processRequest(){

   // Want to access the structs in here as well

 }
```

I try to initialize them this way but just get

"error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

error: ‘head’ has an incomplete type

error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

error: ‘tail’ has an incomplete type"

Is there any way to do this properly?

Also, I will be accessing this linked list of global structs in many threads. So am I right in thinking that I will be able to access any request_struct's  between head and tail as long as they are referenced to by prev or next?

Thanks

Comment: If it is not typo, the struct names are different (`reuqest_struct` you have an `u` character in `reuqest` in structure definition).

Comment: @pmg are you saying in main I should just do `head.next = tail` ? because I've also tried that and I just get _error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct request_struct’_

Comment: @Mahesh ....... I am so stupid..... Sorry everyone.

Comment: See @Mahesh's comment. You have a typo in the struct names.

Comment: @user2799846 Don't worry. Suggestion: When you see messages like `error: invalid use of undefined type`, things you have to check 1. If the type definition is available for the compiler in the current translation unit. 2. Spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Mahesh Thanks, definitely a lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: you already initialize them (to `0`) when you create them.
Now you want to assign them a value.

For C89

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    head.request_time.tv_sec = 42;
    head.request_time.tv_usec = 0;
    head.type = 5;
    head.accountNums[0] = 0;
    head.accountNums[1] = 1;
    // ...
    head.accountNums[9] = 9;
    head.transAmounts[0] = 0;
    // ...
    head.transAmounts[9] = 9;
    head.next = tail;
    head.prev = NULL;

    // same thing for tail
}
```

For C99 there is a shortcut:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    head = (struct request_struct){{42, 0}, 5,
           {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
           {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, tail, NULL};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo, it is **request_struct** in the definition of the struct , after fixing it you can do it like that

```
struct request_struct
{
struct timeval request_time;
int type;
int accountNums[10];
int transAmounts[10];
struct request_struct *next;
struct request_struct *prev;

};

// global structs I want
struct request_struct head = {.request_time = {0}, .type =5, .accountNums ={0},
         .transAmounts={0}, .next = NULL,.prev=NULL };
```